# amazon complians I am not using correct algorithm to sign requests I am

Tags: python, angular, amazon-s3, sha256

so I might need to add the string `"AWS4"` I am using angular and python.

on the python end I calcuate the signature then send it over to the front end to then send the file to aws. I'll just show the signature and payload code:

```
signature = base64.b64encode(hmac.new(aws_secret, policy, hashlib.sha256).digest())
            data = {
                "policy" : policy,
                "signature": signature,
                "key": AWS_UPLOAD_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
                "file_bucket_path": upload_start_path,
                "venuemenuobject" : serializesamplemenu.data,
                "startpath" : upload_start_path,
                "url": url
            }
            return Response(data)
```

then creating the form with the file and sending the request.

```
 let fd = new FormData();
              fd.append('acl', 'private');
              fd.append('Content-Type', contenttype);
              fd.append('AWSAccessKeyId',awspolicy.key);
              fd.append('Policy', awspolicy.policy);
              fd.append('key', awspolicy.startpath);
              fd.append('filename', filename);
              fd.append('Signature', awspolicy.signature);
              fd.append('file', content);
              console.log('the formdata object called');
              this.awsservice.uploadtos3(awspolicy.url,fd)
                .subscribe(
                  (req: any)=>{
                    console.log('the data was uploaded');
                    console.log(req);
                  }
                );
```

and the error:

```
The authorization mechanism you have provided is not supported. Please use AWS4-HMAC-SHA256.
```

according to the docs https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4_signing.html 
we need to add the headers to our request.

So I did that. And yet Still no go.

```
samplemenucreateandpolicy(venuepk, payload){

    const url =  samplemenupolicyandcreate + '/' + String(venuepk);
    return this.http.post(url, payload);
  }

  uploadtos3(url, payload, rawheader){
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    const authheader = 'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=' + String(rawheader.key) + '/' + String(rawheader.date) + '/' + String(rawheader.region) +'/iam/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=content-type;x-amz-date, Signature=' + String(rawheader.signature);
    headers.append('Authorization',authheader);

    return this.http.post(url, payload, {headers: headers});

  }
```

how do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are definitely using Signature Version 2, not V4.

```
signature = base64.b64encode(hmac.new(aws_secret, policy, hashlib.sha256).digest())
```

...and here...

```
fd.append('AWSAccessKeyId',awspolicy.key);
```

This parameter is `X-Amz-Credential`, and contains additional information along with the aws-access-key-id.

> according to the docs ... we need to add the headers to our request.

You are confusing two different interfaces.

What you are doing is a form `POST` upload, which does not use the `Authorization` header.

Review https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-post-example.html.

Comment: thank you. It seems the guide I was using is rather outdated.